# Most efficient way to filter through Javascript array of objects without standard keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say I have this (admittedly bad) structure:

```
var items = [
  {SomeString: [value1,value2...]},
  {AnotherString: [valueX,valueY...]},
  {YetAnotherString: [valueA,valueB...]}
];
```

I want to obtain the array assigned to "AnotherString".

One way (via jQuery) I am using:

```
$.each(items,function(x,item){
    $.each(item,function(key,values){
        if(key=="AnotherString"){
            //...do something
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously this is terribly inefficient, as it loops through needless items.
One way would be to refactor it in a "while(!found)" loop.

My question: what's the most efficient way to filter through such an array?

**Edit:** forgot to clarify that I do not know in advance the key strings. This is used in an external loop where the key strings I am looking for are passed down.

Comment: Well, you're *knowing* the property that you want to access, so what do you need the inner loop for?

Comment: Well in general if your array does not contain > 1000-2000 elements you should not waste time with that matter as loops are very performant. Its just puzzling arround for not much effect. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: Sorry, did not clarify this. I do not actually know the keys in advance. The searched key for example is contained in a <div> that a user clicks.

Comment: Even if the property name is a variable, you can still access it with `item[ keyVariable ]` instead of looping through the entire object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that this structure is bad, why do you stick to it? Just use a normal object:

```
var obj = {
  SomeString: [value1,value2...],
  AnotherString: [valueX,valueY...],
  YetAnotherString: [valueA,valueB...]
};
```

If this is not possible for some reason, convert it dynamically:

```
obj = {};
items.forEach(function(item) {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    obj[key] = item[key];
});
```

This returns an object like the above. Once you have this, just do `obj[someKey]` when needed. No loops.

(This assumes, of course, that all keys are different).

Comment: You are right, it's not possible to change the structure of that particular variable (for various reasons). Sure, one way is to convert it, but you **are** looping anyway in order to do that.

Comment: @pkExec: yes, but you only loop _once_, not on every request.

Comment: I ended up going with your solution. Just a minor gotcha though: Object.keys is not supported in Abomination (aka IE)< 9.0, so i had to use a polyfill for that.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, stripping away jQuery and using [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is the route to the most efficient solution.

```
items.some(function(item) {
    if( item.hasOwnProperty("AnotherString")) {
        // do something with item["AnotherString"]
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Documentation on the `some` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - Polyfill provided